# ¿Cómo eliminar una etiqueta (tag) en Git?

Tags: git, git-tag

Trabajando en una rama, accidentalmente se creó y subió al servidor una etiqueta (*tag*) con un nombre erróneo para la línea de versionado de las *release* que mantenemos. No es un problema grave pero sí una molestia.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar esa etiqueta en local y en el servidor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para eliminarlo localmente:

```
git tag --delete nombreDeltag
```

Para eliminarlo del servidor:

```
git push --delete origin nombreDeltag
```

Reemplaza `nombreDeltag` por el nombre de tu tag

Answer (score 1):

Con esto borras el tag localmente:

```
git tag -d nombreDelTag
```

Y con esto lo borras del servidor (sustituye `origin` por el nombre de tu remoto)

```
git push origin :nombreDelTag
```